# How can I add to HEAD tag using classic ASP server side code?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a need to add META tags inside my HEAD tag using classic ASP vbscript server side code. I am working with a system that uses a header include file (which includes the HEAD tag) on every page. I cannot change this layout. I need to add META content to the HEAD tag using server side code on my individual .asp pages.

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: How is your `<head>` stored in your `#include` file, can you post the structure of that file? At the moment we don't know if it's written out directly from the response buffer or it's stored in a string and written out later. Providing this information will have a direct impact on the advice you are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fairly straightforward.

You can add a meta tag simply by coding it into your VBScript on the server side.  For instance, consider:

```vbs
<%
dim metaString
metaString = "<meta name=""author"" content=""" & myName & """ />"
%>
```

Then in your `<head>` tag you can try...

```
<%= metaString %>
```

Obviously the code that defines the `metaString` in the first place must appear before the use of the variable.

Comment: Their `<head>` is defined in an include that they say they can't change so how does this help?, sorry @Paul if I've missed something. It all depends on how the `#include` defines the `<head>` is it just written out or stored in a string then written out with `Response.Write()`?, answer we just don't know.

Comment: @Lankymart: It's a bit vague - I took this to meant hat he couldn't change the fact that the file was included like this but not that the file itself couldn't be changed.

Comment: thanks @Paul ! I do have access to change the header file, I just can't change the setup/structure. I think this will work. It's just so simple I didn't even think about it!  :)

Comment: No probs, @trevoray. Good luck. :o)